# angular Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to run one of Angular Materials examples but for the life of me I can't figure out why I'm getting this error.

The error I am getting is `Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error`

This is the error report I got: [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=MyApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.8%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DMyApp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:6:416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:24:186%0A%20%20%20%20at%20b%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:23:251)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:23:494%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:38:117%0A%20%20%20%20at%20n%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:7:333)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:37:488)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20eb%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:41:249)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:19:463)

Any ideas what the issue could be? I practically copy-pasted this from their examples website.

Here is the code:

```js
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

```css
.buttondemoBasicUsage section {
  background: #f7f7f7;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em;
  position: relative !important;
  padding-bottom: 10px; }

.buttondemoBasicUsage md-content {
  margin-right: 7px; }

.buttondemoBasicUsage section .md-button {
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px; }

.buttondemoBasicUsage .label {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 7px;
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 0.54; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" class="buttondemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content>

    <section layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="center center" layout-wrap="">
      <md-button class="md-icon-button md-primary" aria-label="Settings">
        <md-icon md-font-icon="icon-home"></md-icon>
      </md-button>
      <md-button class="md-icon-button md-accent" aria-label="Favorite">
        <md-icon md-font-icon="icon-home"></md-icon>
      </md-button>
      <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="More">
        <md-icon md-font-icon="icon-home"></md-icon>
      </md-button>
      <md-button href="http://google.com" title="Launch Google.com in new window" target="_blank" ng-disabled="true" aria-label="Google.com" class="md-icon-button launch">
        <md-icon md-font-icon="icon-home"></md-icon>
      </md-button>
      <div class="label">Icon Button</div>
    </section>
  </md-content>
</div>

<!--
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved. 
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be in foundin the LICENSE file at http://material.angularjs.org/license.
-->
```

Comment: Are all three of these modules, `['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache']` defined somewhere in one of the 8 files you're loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you reference the .js file related to your angular app? 
I can just see the external javascript dependencies but nothing related to your app - controller. Take care about the order you're importing it

Comment: What is the correct order of importing then? I copy pasted it from a working example on the angular website.

Comment: Think about what needs what. Your app and controllers need angular framework then you have to put them after angular.js file

Comment: E.g. If you put your module and your controllers in the file myapp.js, this file must be referenced after angular.js.

<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="myapp.js"></script>

Answer (score 30):

Most probably you are missing svg icons

```
<script src="http://ngmaterial.assets.s3.amazonaws.com/svg-assets-cache.js"></script>
```

Comment: I thought this file would be in the material-design-icons directory after installing with npm, but I don't see anything that matches. Is this file included somewhere else?

Answer (score 4):

Change the module script to remove the reference to material.svgAssetsCache and the demo will run but without the final row of buttons - which reference "local" image resources.

If you grab a copy of the icons(**bower install material-design-icons**) and locate the relevant 24px .svg files and pop them in (say) /img/icons/ from the root of your web site (adjusting file names and path as required) then even this section will work just fine.

The demo is rather off-putting when you think about it as it is likely to be chosen as a first stab at trying things out yet it only works within the CodePen sand-tray.

Comment: You can use this JavaScript library to draw the icons https://klarsys.github.io/angular-material-icons/ although you have to do some positioning to get them perfectly located within (say) a fab. This line: <ng-md-icon icon="android" style="fill: white; position: relative; top: 6px;" size="24" ></ng-md-icon> placed the icon in the "android" fab example.

Answer (score -3):

You need to add:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
```