# try to use ngMaterial but I get $injector:modulerr error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I start using angular material today but when I want to use ngMaterial in myproject I get [an error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=MyApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.6%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dmaterial.svgAssetsCache%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.5.6%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253Dmaterial.svgAssetsCache%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Error%2520(native)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Farticlelist.com%252Fdesktopmodules%252FBarrizon%252FScripts%252FAngular1.x%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A412%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Farticlelist.com%252Fdesktopmodules%252FBarrizon%252FScripts%252FAngular1.x%252Fangular.min.js%253A25%253A235%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520b%2520(http%253A%252F%252Farticlelist.com%252Fdesktopmodules%252FBarrizon%252FScripts%252FAngular1.x%252Fangular.min.js%253A24%253A282)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Farticlelist.com%252Fdesktopmodules%252FBarrizon%252FScripts%252FAngular1.x%252Fangular.min.js%253A25%253A20%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Farticlelist.com%252Fdesktopmodules%252FBarrizon%252FScripts%252FAngular1.x%252Fangular.min.js%253A39%253A374%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520q%2520(http%253A%252F%252Farticlelist.com%252Fdesktopmodules%252FBarrizon%252FScripts%252FAngular1.x%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A355)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(http%253A%252F%252Farticlelist.com%252Fdesktopmodules%252FBarrizon%252FScripts%252FAngular1.x%252Fangular.min.js%253A39%253A222)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Farticlelist.com%252Fdesktopmodules%252FBarrizon%252FScripts%252FAngular1.x%252Fangular.min.js%253A39%253A391%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520q%2520(http%253A%252F%252Farticlelist.com%252Fdesktopmodules%252FBarrizon%252FScripts%252FAngular1.x%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A355)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Farticlelist.com%2Fdesktopmodules%2FBarrizon%2FScripts%2FAngular1.x%2Fangular.min.js:6:412%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Farticlelist.com%2Fdesktopmodules%2FBarrizon%2FScripts%2FAngular1.x%2Fangular.min.js:40:134%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(http:%2F%2Farticlelist.com%2Fdesktopmodules%2FBarrizon%2FScripts%2FAngular1.x%2Fangular.min.js:7:355)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Farticlelist.com%2Fdesktopmodules%2FBarrizon%2FScripts%2FAngular1.x%2Fangular.min.js:39:222)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Farticlelist.com%2Fdesktopmodules%2FBarrizon%2FScripts%2FAngular1.x%2Fangular.min.js:39:391%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(http:%2F%2Farticlelist.com%2Fdesktopmodules%2FBarrizon%2FScripts%2FAngular1.x%2Fangular.min.js:7:355)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Farticlelist.com%2Fdesktopmodules%2FBarrizon%2FScripts%2FAngular1.x%2Fangular.min.js:39:222)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20db%20(http:%2F%2Farticlelist.com%2Fdesktopmodules%2FBarrizon%2FScripts%2FAngular1.x%2Fangular.min.js:43:246)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(http:%2F%2Farticlelist.com%2Fdesktopmodules%2FBarrizon%2FScripts%2FAngular1.x%2Fangular.min.js:21:19) ...

I try to use angular material locally and my intention is very simple: using `<md-button>`:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" class="buttondemoBasicUsage" ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="">
    <md-content>

        <section layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="center center" layout-wrap="">
            <md-button>{{title1}}</md-button>
            <md-button md-no-ink="" class="md-primary">Primary (md-noink)</md-button>
            <md-button ng-disabled="true" class="md-primary">Disabled</md-button>
            <md-button class="md-warn">{{title4}}</md-button>
            <div class="label">Flat</div>
        </section>
    </md-content>
</div>
```

i add every script that I suspect can solve my issue as here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/desktopmodules/Barrizon/Scripts/Angular1.x/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/desktopmodules/Barrizon/Scripts/Material/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/desktopmodules/Barrizon/Scripts/Material/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/desktopmodules/Barrizon/Scripts/Material/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/desktopmodules/Barrizon/Scripts/Material/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DesktopModules/mvc/Barrizon/LArticle/List/Resources/JS/Barrizon.LArticle.Settings.js"></script>
```

and the last js (`Barrizon.LArticle.Settings.js`) is which i write my custom js in there:

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngAria', 'ngMessages', 'ngMaterial', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.title1 = 'Button';
    $scope.title4 = 'Warn';
    $scope.isDisabled = true;

    $scope.googleUrl = 'http://google.com';

});
```

is anyone knows how can i pass this error?

thanks a lot

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36086506/949476

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add all these scripts in your code along with your custom js,

```
<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.9/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ngmaterial.assets.s3.amazonaws.com/svg-assets-cache.js"></script>
```

Plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/ZWUIiLRaJOvC5WMrMZQq?p=preview